# Is the number of child nodes equal for all nodes or 0

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am trying to do a code which would state whether the number of child nodes for all parent nodes is equal. In other words, if all parents have the same amount of children. If some node is not a parent, it's not considered a false. However, my code is not working. It doesn't return false when the last level doesn't match the expected number.

I have already determined, that all the child nodes need to have the same amount of children as the root node.

```
public boolean equalNumberOfChildren() {
    boolean correct = true;
    for (Person child : children) {
        correct = child.equalNumberOfChildren();
        if (correct == true && child.children.size() == children.size() || child.children.size()==0) {
            correct = true;
        }else {
            correct = false;
        }
    }
    return correct;
}
```

Comment: "my code is not working" what's not working? please give expected and actual output

Comment: @SharonBenAsher It doesn't return false when the last level doesn't match the expected number.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming children is a field of type NodeList, what is the depth (i.e. how many levels) of your xml structure or is it arbitrary depth.
We are talking w3c xml dom here, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override the result of the recursive call. you need to inquire on the children only if the recursive call was found to be "correct"

```
    correct = child.equalNumberOfChildren();  // assign value to correct
    // continue only if not found discrepency 
    if (correct && (child.children.size() == children.size() || child.children.size()==0)) {
        correct = true;
    }else {
        correct = false;
    }
}
return correct;
```